# Fight Club book editions and different text passages

Tags: chuck-palahniuk, fight-club, textual-history

I found out that there are different editions of *Fight Club* that contain different text passages. I cannot find any page that would describe these differences and I don't know which version is the original one.

Example of book differences (one of many):

After the following text in chapter 6:

> Except for their humping, Marla and Tyler are never in the same room. If Tyler’s around, Marla ignores him. This is familiar ground.

In version 1 is the following text:

> “The big sleep, `Valley of the Dogs’ style. “Where even if someone loves you enough to save your life, they still castrate you.” Marla looks at me as if I’m the one humping her and says, “I can’t win with you, can I?”

In version 2 is the following different text:

> My father always said, “Get married before the sex gets boring or you’ll never get married.” My mother said, “Never buy anything with a nylon zipper.”  My parents never said anything you’d want to embroider on a cushion."

I am not sure if these differences are between paperback and e-book editions. I have a Czech version of the paperback that contains text from version 2. I have been able to find the online English e-books only with the version 1 text.

I cannot find any information about different editions of *Fight Club*. Can you help me? The new rerelease of the book should contain only the new introduction by the author.

Comment: You're onto something and nobody believed you! I have just noticed a similar thing with the ending.

Answer (score 1):

Both are in my copy of Fight Club, but they are on the page after each other, in the same place. Maybe you accidentally skipped them somehow?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please can you [edit] your answer to include an exact quote from the passage in your book, to show exactly how they appear after each other? Then it will be more easy for readers to check, and maybe to search and find different editions online.